# SwiftUI Foreground Content has inconsistent color

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
 let lobbyViewModel = LobbyViewModel()
       let userViewModel = UserViewModel(lobbyViewModel: lobbyViewModel)
     
        Button {
        
            lobby = createLobby()
            
            isClicked = true
           
            
        } label: {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45)
            
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
               .frame(width: width * 0.925, height: height * 0.225, alignment: .center)
               .blendMode(.colorDodge)
               .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 2, x: 5, y: 10)
          
               .overlay {

                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 105)
                      
                       .frame(width: width*0.35, height: height*0.065)
                      
                       .foregroundStyle(gradientStyle)
                       .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 5, y: 5)
                       
                       .overlay {
                           Text(callout)
                               .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                               .foregroundColor(Color("White"))
                           
                       }
                       
                       .offset(x: width*0.31, y: -height*0.115)
                       
                   VStack {
                      
                       Text(title)
                           .foregroundColor(Color("Black"))
                           .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                           .frame(height: height * 0.035)
                           .padding(.top, height * 0.05)
                       
                       Text(description)
                           .foregroundColor(.gray)
                           .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                           .minimumScaleFactor(0.75)
                           .lineLimit(4)
                           .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                           .frame(width: width * 0.8, height: height * 0.125, alignment: .center)
                           .padding(.horizontal)
                       
                       Spacer() // Take up 2/3 of the VStack height
                   }
                   
                   .padding(.horizontal)
                   .clipped()
               }.padding(height*0.03)
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isClicked, destination: {
    
            
            if let lobby {
          
                WaitingRoomView(lobby: lobby, user: user, selectedItem: selectedItem)
                    .environmentObject(lobbyViewModel)
                    .environmentObject(userViewModel)
                   
            }
    
            
        })
```

I currently have a gradient background with some white cards placed in the foreground, when I place three cards the top two cards have a grey tint, while the bottom card is straight white, making the cards look off on the screen.

I've tried working with .blendMode(), and hardcoding the color away from .white but it doesn't seem to solve my underlying issue